# What is minimum Eulerian partition?

Tags: graph-theory, integer-partitions

I have a homework in my graph course. It asks something about minimum Eulerian partition but it doesn't give any information about it. I googled it but couldn't come up anything useful and clear. Is there anybody here who can explain me what it is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An Eulerian partition of $G$ is a partition of the edges of $G$ into edge-disjoint circuits. (That is, different circuits may share vertices, but they may not have any edges in common.) I imagine that a minimal Eulerian partition is one that has the smallest possible number of circuits, though I’m happy to be corrected by someone better acquainted with the subject.

Comment: thakns for the input

Comment: @newbieee: You’re welcome.